# Why can't I implement my Vector methods on this instance of VectorQueue?

Tags: java, types, interface, queue, abstract-data-type

The class `VectorQueue` here is a queue data structure implementing vector methods. In my test class at the bottom I can successfully compile code such as " myVector.enqueue(20); " where myVector is an instance of the `VectorQueue` class. It's actual type is `Queue` - see here

```
Queue<Integer> myVector = new VectorQueue<Integer>();
```

My question is this: Is there no way to use the vector methods on the instance "myVector" once it has been actualized as type Queue? I've tried the following:

```
((Vector<T>) myVector).insertAtRank(2,5);
```

I also tried making my main class VectorQueue implement Queue and Vector interfaces, but it didn't help. I wondered to myself also, why can't something have multiple actualized types?

```
package W7;

public class VectorQueue<T> implements Queue<T> {

public Vector<T> myVector = new ArrayVector<T>();

public void enqueue(T e) {
    myVector.insertAtRank(myVector.size(), e);
}

public T front() {
    return myVector.elemAtRank(0);
}

public T dequeue() {
    return myVector.removeAtRank(0);
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return myVector.isEmpty();
}

public int size() {
    return myVector.size();
}

public String toString(){
    return myVector.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws VectorFullException,
        RankOutOfBoundsException {

    Queue<Integer> myVector = new VectorQueue<Integer>();

    try {

        myVector.enqueue(10);
        System.out.println(myVector);

        myVector.enqueue(5);
        System.out.println(myVector);

        myVector.dequeue();
        System.out.println(myVector);

        myVector.enqueue(15);
        System.out.println(myVector);

        myVector.enqueue(3);
        System.out.println(myVector);

        myVector.dequeue();
        System.out.println(myVector);

        myVector.enqueue(7);
        System.out.println(myVector);

        myVector.dequeue();
        System.out.println(myVector);

        myVector.enqueue(20);
        System.out.println(myVector);

        ((Vector<T>) myVector).insertAtRank(2,5);

    } catch (VectorFullException RankOutOfBoundsException) {
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
    int total = 0;
    while(! myVector.isEmpty()){
        total += myVector.dequeue();
    }
    System.out.println("The total size of the contents: " + total);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating an instance for interface reference use your class' reference.                      `VectorQueue<Integer> myVector = new VectorQueue<Integer>();`

Comment: extend the class Vector<T> and also implement Queue<T>, that you can use Vector's methods too.

Comment: Vector<T> is an interface so it can only be implemented, not extended. I tried using both the Vector and Queue implementations together on the VectorQueue class, which I thought should work, but no..It didn't.

Comment: Vector<E> is a class not an interface FYI.

Comment: I'm not using java classes though, I'm creating my own ones. Hence, why Vector<T> is an interface. Anyway, I found the answer --> myVector.vector.insertAtRank(2, 3);   I had to access the ArrayVector methods by accessing the instance Vector which i called vector.